# Why does recordset.RecordCount equal 1 but recordset.EOF and recordset.BOF both equal True

Tags: vbscript

I have a very simple query that only returns one record.  When I try to get the value out of the only column in the only record, I get "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record."  What's going on here?  The code that is causing the error doesn't even execute if RecordCount is 0 and I have verified that the recordset does in fact contain a record.

Code is below.  Error is thrown when trying to set strDN.  It's so dead simple but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

EDITED TO INCLUDE COMMAND

```
<LDAP://DC=something,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(employeeID=01234567));distinguishedName;subtree

Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute


    If adoRecordset.RecordCount > 0 Then


        strDN = adoRecordset.Fields("distinguishedName").Value

        Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDN)

        objGroup.add(objUser.ADsPath)

    End if
```

Comment: I've edited my question.  The command is included in the code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recordcount property leaves the cursor at the end of the recordset, so you cannot then obtain the record (eof=true), you must movefirst. Use a different cursor type, because the default cursor type is forward only:

```
'' Assign cursorType that allows forward and backward movement.
adoRecordset.cursorType = 3 ''adOpenStatic
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_rs_cursortype.asp

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
If Not adoRecordset.EOF And Not adoRecordset.BOF Then
...
End If
```

For This Scenario

Comment: This is probably the best way to check if at least one record is found.  The RecordCount property behaves differently depending on the cursor type.

Comment: Well, I have absolutely no idea why it works, but if I use BOF and EOF instead of RecordCount to check for the presence of a record, everything works fine.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: see remou's answer as to why this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

-EDIT-
Have a look at the following link. There are some causes listed, and solutions for most of them:

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-bof-or-eof-errors.html

[I was wrong about this - thanks, Dave] I believe you need to call adoRecordset.MoveNext (or whatever the call is) before attempting to get the value of a field in the recordset.

Comment: If I do that I get the same error, it's just thrown on the adoRecordset.MoveNext instead of when I set strDN

Comment: ADO in ASP & vbScript automatically reads the first record, unlike the ADO reader in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute    

    If adoRecordset.RecordCount > 0 Then

        adoRecordset.MoveFirst 'Move to the first record

        strDN = adoRecordset.Fields("distinguishedName").Value

        Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDN)

        objGroup.add(objUser.ADsPath)

    End if
```

Comment: I have tried this but I get the same error, it's just thrown on adoRecordset.MoveFirst

Comment: @res: What type of cursor are you using?  See Remou's answer.  You have to be using a forward and backward moving cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `adoRecordSet.Requery()` after RecordCount request can also help in this situation, if your query isn't that complex to execute it the second time.